# what is docker run -w flag?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Came across a docker run command that uses -w flag.

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/project \
         -w /project \
         -p 8081:8081 \
         gcr.io/base-project/myoh:v1
```

Any idea what the `-w` flag is for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just run `docker run --help` in your shell.

`-w, --workdir string                 Working directory inside the container`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir